# How to approach the Data Visualization aspect of D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I need help figuring out a starting level project for Data Visualization. Do you think just making some random project that doesn't actually use accurate or realistic data is a good way to start? I have been working on something here at [bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/maxcell/7f8d71b0c8cb55c8d325) because I really like space and whatnot (also, this just practice, no need to critique it unless there is a huge flaw). It is simply a simulator of planetary orbits around the sun, even though it is not scaled appropriately. However, it got me started with understanding D3 and its syntax. But, I feel like that is just more about getting an idea of what D3 can do. Even though that is a rather interesting start, I would really like to understand on how to approach the exploratory analysis process.

I am just unsure how to approach the problem at hand. Do you just look at some data and figure out how to make a story for it? I am new, so I apologize for advance for something so trivial, however, I felt that this would be a great community pose the problem and arrive to a rather good conclusion.

I would gladly like to hear from everyone with their opinions and advice.

Comment: I would suggest you to go through this tutorial https://www.dashingd3js.com/table-of-contents
an then go to the bl.ocks.

Comment: d3 is huge, flexible and extensible, bug sometimes you don't know what to do with it. I would [study some svg](http://svgpocketguide.com/book/) and I would get to the world of the [d3 layouts](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Layouts), there is a whole world of ideas there. 
[Use the force luke](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout).

Comment: Also follow this tutorial about the d3 key concept, how to bind the data http://ui-cloud.com/web-based-visualization-part-1-the-d3-js-key-concept/. Thanks to [stephen-thomas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1403714/stephen-thomas)

Comment: Thank you everyone.! @Cyril, I have been actually looking at dashingd3js. But I didn't know how well/poor it was but I appreciate the fact that you mention it! I will definitely follow through with it.

Comment: Thank you @DavidLemon too! I definitely love all the suggestions as well. They seem very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 can basically do anything ranging from 3d data visualizations to graphically representing data.

Also, d3 uses a lot of SVG techniques.

If you are looking to understand what all can be built out with d3, take a look at the below link:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery

The best way to approach would be figuring out 3-4 components you can build out like below:
- Word Cloud
- A Graph component
- Tree Map Structre
- World Map 
Once you prototype it, you can tweak the prototype to connect to some dummy JSOn data through Ajax.

Hope this helps.!!

Comment: Thank you so much for this information! That's is a really all I was looking for. I have been looking at the Gallery but I just wasn't sure how to approach the technique. This truly helped.